# if add new blog in database than sent mail to all subscriber to notified current blog in Django

Tags: python, django

Note: Add new blog only admin panell.
model.py

```
class blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    blog_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    blog_sub_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_sub_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    written_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Prymus Brandcom')
    image_banner= models.ImageField(upload_to='image_banner')
    medium_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='medium_thumbnail')
    content = RichTextField() # RichTextField is used for paragraphs
    is_authentic=models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta: # Plurizing the class name explicitly
        verbose_name_plural = 'blog'
     
    def __str__(self): # Dundar Method
        return self.blog_title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Saving Modefied Changes
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_title)
        #super(blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        super(blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def snippet(self):
        return self.content[:300]
```

and it's my subscriber table:

```
class subscriber(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,default="")
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self): # Dundar Method
        return self.name
```

Add new blog in blog table than send mail to all registerd user in subscriber table
???

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/) to achieve that.

(Assuming you have [formated your models class on PascalCase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id39))

In your `models.py`:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail


@receiver(signal=signal=models.signals.pre_save, sender=Blog)
def email_on_blogpost_saved(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # You'll must check if this `blog`` have been ever sent to suscribers   
    # because this function will be executed on each save that include modification. 
    recipient_mails  = Subscriber.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)
    new_mail = ('New post from XXX ', 'FooMessage', 'name@example.com', recipient_mails)
    send_mass_mail((new_mail, ), fail_silently=False)
```

Add a Boolean Field to `have_been_sent` for avoiding resend mails:

```
@receiver(signal=signal=models.signals.pre_save, sender=Blog)
def email_on_new_blogpost(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    current_blog = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    if current_blog.have_been_sent:
      pass
    else:
        recipient_mails  = Subscriber.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)
        new_mail = ('New post from XXX ', 'FooMessage', 'name@example.com', recipient_mails)
        send_mass_mail((new_mail, ), fail_silently=False)
```

Don't forget to configure Django for mailling by adjusting your `settings.py` as seen in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#smtp-backend)